# SAPUI5: How to reset SmartTable P13N dialog?

Tags: sapui5

I have a smart table in my UI5 application. When I visit one of the objects of my WorklistView, I will set a filter in my SmartTable's personalisation dialog (P13N). When I navigate back to my worklist and try to visit another entry I will see the filter that have set in the previous visit is there yet!

[image: Smart Table P13N dialog]

How can reset the P13N of a SmartTable each time that I visit the targeted view!

I need to call a function of the smart table in my `onRouteMatched` event handler. But I don't know what function or method can do this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer provided for my another question in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620541/how-to-use-applyvariant-function-on-smarttables/48622335#48622335), I finally reached to an answer for this question. I had to use `applyVariant` function in the `onBindingChange` function of the view.

```
resetPersonalisation: function() {
        var oSmartTable = this.getView().byId("mySmartTableId");            
        oSmartTable.applyVariant({});
}
```

Then the personalisation model will be reset each time the specific route is matched.