# How to use applyVariant function on smarttables?

Tags: sapui5

How can I use `applyVariant` function on a `smarttable`?

The documentation exist here:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/methods/applyVariant

But it does not say what the structure of `oVariantJSON` parameter should be!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to apply a filter on your smart table and in the `beforeRebindTable` event of your smart table try to use the following code:

```
onBeforeRebindTable: function(oEvent) {
   var oSmartTable = oEvent.getSource();
   console.log(oSmartTable.fetchVariant());
}
```

By using the `fetchVariant` function, you can see what the structure of the variation is. For example for `filter` it is like this:

```
{
     filter: {
                    filterItems: [{
                        columnKey: "YourSelectedColumn",
                        exclude: false, 
                        operation: "EQ", 
                        value1: "SomeEnteredValue",
                        value2: ""
                    }]
                }
}
```

Then you can use this object for the `applyVariant` function as its first parameter.

Comment: Thanks. As you said I used the `beforeRebindTable` event, and extracted the object for Group and sort as well.
For Group:

     `{
         group: {
                groupItems:[{
                                 columnKey: "xyz",
                                 operation: "GroupAscending",
                                 showIfGrouped: true
                                 }]
                     }
      }`

Comment: And for Sort:
`{sort: sortItems: [{ columnKey: "xyz", operation:"Ascending"}]}`